# Could sharing data using a service replace route params?

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular app and sharing multiple objects along the app. These objects must be synchronized and hold the current state along all components.

So I created services to handle each object and its changes using `BehaviorSubject` and subscribed to it where needed.

BUT in some cases I was thinking it could be achieved using the Angular router and its params, which make me invest more time to pass a complex object as query params.

Today I just realized that I've never used query params in my app and my URLs are too simple, which I have never seen.

So my question is, is it OK or would that be a weak point in my app?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it only makes sense to pass the data as parameters of the route if you really want them in the url. They are OK in the route if the user can save the url and then by entering it can appear in the same state of the view only using them.

For instance if you have a blog app and you have the route

```
http://myblog-example/entry-cool?tags=cool;super_cool
```

If the tags parameters (the tags here) are really necessary to render the page ok, but if they are something that you will retrieve form the DB, do not put them in the route. You then should use a service and an observable (or subject) to get them and display them in your page.